# Multiple testing correction in two dimensions

Tags: correlation, least-squares, multiple-comparisons, statsmodels

During one of our studies, we tried to investigate if there is a correlation between compound toxicity and specific protein expression levels. Both were measured in a considerable number of cell lines. To analyze the data, I've performed pairwise (protein-compound) ordinary least squares calculations using the `statsmodels` python library.

[image: correlation plot]

The plot shows an excerpt of our data, where the diamonds denote *p*-Values < 0.05 while the color is the Pearson correlation coefficient *r*.

I am not quite sure if and how multiple testing correction should or can be applied to the *p*-Values in this case since protein and compound data is correlated multiple times in rows or columns, respectively.